# How to incorporate If statement in Find on cmd.exe or Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, find

I have a logger file containing many lines of information. I want to create a script where it finds all lines containing "::Directory" ONLY if the FOLLOWING line is NOT "::Calling subInACL" --> puts all the found lines into a text file.

If there's a timestamp, that's a new line.

The SubinACL line for a particular account (ie. xx1) will ALWAYS follow the "::Directory" line. So really all I need is a code that checks if the line following a "::Directory" line begins with "::Calling". If it does, do not include it in the output.

EX: If the logger file contains

```
10:03:11 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Chem\xx1 created successfully.
10:03:11 AM::Calling subInACL (for ownership) with arguments:  /file \\025.aaa.yyy.com\Home10\Chem\xx1 /setowner=aaa\xx1
10:03:11 AM::Calling subInACL (for perms) with arguments:  /file \\025.aaa.yyy.com\Home10\Chem\xx1 /grant=aaa\xx1=C
10:03:12 AM::Directory \\025.aaa.yyy.com\Home10\Chem\xx1 given ACLs successfully.
10:16:15 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx2 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx3 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx4 created successfully.
```

I need it to return the Directory paths

```
10:16:15 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx2 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx3 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx4 created successfully.
```

BECAUSE they did not have a "subInACL" also created for their account. When a "subinACL" is not created for an account, this is an error, so i need to find all the accounts for which it was not created.

I know I can use

```
find "::Directory" logger.txt > found.txt
```

But this returns ALL "::Directory" lines. How do I incorporate an IF statement or regular expression where it only returns the ones who do not have "::Calling subInACL" as the following line. Can I do this directly on the cmd line without calling a batch file to run? I know I can also use Powershell .. if that's easier?

I'm using the cmd.exe on Windows.

Comment: Why the `10:03:11 AM::Directory \\aaa...` entry is not included in the output? It also have not an "subInACL" entry with the same name... Do you want lines filtered by _TWO_ conditions? (not have "subInACL" with same name **nor** be followed by "subInACL"). This point is not clear!

Comment: I just need the lines that start with" ::Directory" AND DO NOT have a SUBINACL created for that same account (ie. xx1).  I do not need any lines that contain "::Calling subinACL". That is just a determinant of whether or not I need the "::Directory" line for that account. 
That entry is not included because it had a SUBINACL created for it. So account xx1 is safe. On the other hand, accounts xx2,xx3,xx4 did not have subinACL created so i need them in the output file

Comment: Wow! **1**: in the **question description** you said: "finds all lines containing "::Directory" ONLY if the FOLLOWING line is NOT "::Calling subInACL". Then, why "10:03:12 AM::Directory \\025.aaa..." is not included? It's FOLLOWING line is NOT "::Calling subInACL"!!! **2**: In previous comment you said something different: "lines that start with" ::Directory" AND DO NOT have a SUBINACL created for that same account (ie. xx1)" ??? **`:(`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most easily handled in a tool such as awk, but, with adequate effort, it can be done in a cmd shell script. ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION is key to the solution. You need to be able to use variables inside the FOR loop.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET WAITING_FOR_NEXT_LINE=0

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN (`TYPE log.txt`) DO (
    SET V=%%s
    SET LOOKING_FOR=!V:~11,12!

    IF !WAITING_FOR_NEXT_LINE! EQU 1 (
        IF "!V:~11,10!" NEQ "::Calling " (
            ECHO !LAST_LINE!
        )
    )

    SET WAITING_FOR_NEXT_LINE=0

    IF "!LOOKING_FOR!" EQU "::Directory " (
        SET LAST_LINE=%%s
        SET WAITING_FOR_NEXT_LINE=1
    )
)

IF %WAITING_FOR_NEXT_LINE% EQU 1 (ECHO %LAST_LINE%)

EXIT /B 0
```

You need something to know that the next line should push the previous line out. Equally important, it needs to be reset after it has found one.

```
C:>logprocessor.bat
10:03:12 AM::Directory \\025.aaa.yyy.com\Home10\Chem\xx1 given ACLs successfully.
10:16:15 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx2 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx3 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx4 created successfully.
```

If you want the ACL line omitted, add a test for the end of the line.

```
IF !WAITING_FOR_NEXT_LINE! EQU 1 (
    IF "!V:~11,10!" NEQ "::Calling " (
        IF "!LAST_LINE:~-21!" EQU "created successfully." (
            ECHO !LAST_LINE!
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: @HarryL: accordingly to your specifications, the `10:03:12 AM::Directory \\025.aaa.yyy.com\Home10\Chem\xx1 given ACLs successfully.` line should _not_ appear in the output, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "prevLine="
for /F "tokens=1-3*" %%a in (logger.txt) do (
   set "word=%%b"
   if "!word:~-9!" neq "::Calling" (
      if defined prevLine echo !prevLine!
      for %%x in ("%%c") do set "thisAcc=%%~Nx"
      if "!thisAcc!" equ "!badAcc!" (
         set "prevLine="
      ) else (
         set "prevLine=%%a %%b %%c %%d"
      )
      set "badAcc="
   ) else (
      set "prevLine="
      set "badAcc=!thisAcc!"
   )
)
if defined prevLine echo !prevLine!
```

Output:

```
10:16:15 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx2 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx3 created successfully.
10:16:48 AM::Directory \\aaa.yyy.com\ABC\Civil\xx4 created successfully.
```